# Select table from a different PostgreSQL schema in Laravel 4

Tags: sql, postgresql, pdo, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, how do you use a table from another schema (other than the default schema defined in `database.php`) to query against?

The L4 docs do not show any sign of being able to do this...

Comment: hi, did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://laravel.com/docs/database

define another schema config in the connections array

```
'pgsql' => array(
    'driver'   => 'pgsql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'database',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
    'schema'   => 'public',
),
'newConnection' => array(
    'driver'   => 'pgsql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'database',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
    'schema'   => 'public',
),
```

then just switch to it, per the docs:

```
$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);
```

Comment: Can I ask how to use this:
`$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);`
Does foo refers to either `pgsql', `mysql`, etc?

Comment: how does this answer the question of accessing different schemas in the same database? you just said how to configure more than one connection and both refer to the same schema (public).

the OP is asking how you would do a query like this:

select *
from security.user
inner join company.person on (...)

he wants to know how do you access both security and company schemas at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

the question was: How to use an alternate schema in queries?

the answer was to define another schema, then choose to connect to it.
example:

```
$schema_conn = DB::connection('{ARRAY_KEY_FOR_OTHER_SCHEMA_CONFIG}');
$query = $schema_conn->where('property', 'value')->get();
```